# Orchard Alternate Shape Template Not Displaying Values

Tags: orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard and have watched both the Pluralsight "Orchard Fundamentals" and "Advanced Orchard" tutorials. Its a great platform, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a couple of things.

I'd like to create a blog showcase banner on the home page only that rotates blog posts on the site. I have the HTML sliced up and functioning on an HTML template. The banner looks like this:

http://arerra.com/news-slideshow.jpg

So far I have done the following:

1. I've created a Blog called "Articles" and have placed a single post in there for testing.
2. Added a Layer called "ArticleList" where I have placed a Widget for "Recent Blog Posts"
3. I've created a custom layout for the home page called "Layout-Url-HomePage.cshtml" in my theme.
4. In my Theme "Views" folder, I have created a file called "Widget.Wrapper.cshtml" with only `@Display(Model.Child)` in it to remove the `<article><header/><footer /><article>` tags globally from the widgets.
5. Added a file in "Views > Parts > Blogs.RecentBlogPosts.cshtml" to control the layout of my shape. The code is the following:

   ```
   @using Orchard.ContentManagement;
   @{
       IEnumerable<object> blogPosts = Model.ContentItems.ContentItems;
   }

   @if (blogPosts != null) {
   <div class="container news-slider">
       <ul class="slide-images">
           @foreach (dynamic post in blogPosts) {
                string title = post.Title;
                ContentItem item = post.ContentItem;

                <img src="/Themes/MountainWestHoops/Content/img/placeholder-700x380.jpg" alt="@title" class="active" />
           }
       </ul>

       @foreach (dynamic post in blogPosts) {
           string title = post.Title;
           string body = post.Body;
           ContentItem item = post.ContentItem;

           <div class="featured-story threeD active">
               <h1>@title</h1>
               <p>@body @Html.ItemDisplayLink("READ MORE", item)</p>
           </div>
       }

       <aside>
           <ul class="tabs">
               @foreach (dynamic post in blogPosts) {
                   string title = post.Title;
                   string url = post.Url;
                   ContentItem item = post.ContentItem;

                   <li><a href="@url"><h3>@title</h3></a></li>
               }
           </ul>

           <div class="ad-three-day-trial">
               <a href=""><img src="/Themes/Content/img/placeholder-260x190.gif" /></a>
           </div>
       </aside>
   </div>
   }
   ```
6. My HTML is rendering properly, but none of the values that I have specified are showing up.
7. I am using the "Shape Tracer" module to see what template is being used. What is funny, is that the @Html.ItemDisplayLink("READ MORE", item) is rendering the article's URL, and if I replace the "READ MORE" with the string title, the title renders properly.

What am I doing wrong here that is causing strings to not display? Am I missing a larger point and misunderstanding the fundamentals? The tutorials seems to say that you can simply move around parts, but in this case, I need to have very specific markup for this slider to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your source was http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/27/taking-over-list-rendering-in-orchard.aspx

That is a rather old post, and the way the title is handled has changed since then.

The DisplayLink works because the only correct property here is `post.ContentItem`, which is what that API takes. `post.Title` and `post.Body` on the other hand are very likely null, which is why you see nothing. To access the title, you can use `post.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title` and to get the body, `post.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text`.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand! Yes, that was actually the article that I took this from. Now that I look at the Shape Tracer, this makes much more sense.